# class AB amplifier input resistances

Tags: resistors, amplifier, resistance, input

I was wondering if you could help me out, what would be the effect of changing R1 & R2. I have looked online, but mustn't be searching in the right place!
My guess is that you would adjust them to minimise crossover distortion, are there any other effects?
your help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
Ben

[image: AB Amplifier Circuit]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp47.gif?81223b))</sub>

Comment: Input impedance of the circuit as a whole changes too.

Answer (score 2):

It's a tradeoff. If you reduce R1 and R2 you increase the bias current in the two power transistors, and this will markedly increase power dissipation of the amplifier. At the same time, crossover distortion will also decrease. So the choice of resistors (and DC current level) is a designer's tradeoff.

Comment: I believe there is an optimal bias point for crossover distortion. It is not the case that higher bias always reduces crossover distortion. Source is Douglas Self's book on amplifier design, which may not be authoritative, but seemed pretty convincing when I read it.